# Rewrite redirect and vhost

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, vhosts, archlinux

I want to know if it's possible (and how) to redirect an URL to a specific port of vhost without changing the URL.

Example:

```
http://foo.example.com:80/bar
|
| "include"
|
http://foo.example.com:8765

# foo is a vhost.
# 80 is an Apache port.
# 8765 is a GNU/GPL server port.
```

I want to display informations of GNU/GPL server using apache by URL http://foo.example.com:80/bar without redirecting. The purpose is to implement the application running under GNU/GPL to my Apache application without change port and keep a clean URL.

```
Archlinux 3.10.23
Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
PHP 5.5.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a working virtualhost responding at http://foo.example.com:80
you can enable mod_proxy and use "ProxyPass" directive:

ProxyPass /bar http://foo.example.com:8765

Comment: Ok thanks!
But if I use a POST method on /bar, the ProxyPass directive will redirect to http://foo.example.com:8765 with our without POST informations?!